# How do I know if I'm looking at Java interface or implementation file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with an old Java project, which uses the naming convention where interface is named MassiveWormholeGenerator and its implementation is named MassiveWormholeGeneratorImpl. Point is that the names are so long that the end of the file name is not visible in Eclipse editor tab. This means that I have to spend time to determine if I'm looking at the interface or implementation. Is there an easy way to keep this information visible constantly?

NamingConventionFlameWars > /dev/null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Show in Breadcrumb action does just this. It can be found from the editor's popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

Title bar of the eclipse shows the full name of the file selected in editor

Comment: So it does. You just made me notice that my title bar font is unreadable.